# Overleaped heatmap doesn't show correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I have a heatmap plotted above an image (as shown on image link [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcsXT.jpg)), with gaussian filter and normalize data. The main issue is that there is no value under 92 on the y axis, so the plot doesnt start on (0,0), instead start on (0,92). So, when I put together both pictures (heatmap and background image), there is an abrupt cut on the graph (as shown on 2nd link, where is the heatmap without background).

So, how can I extend the axis on the heatmap so it start on (0,0)?

Below is the code that I'm currently using to plot both images. Thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

x = df['x_data']
y = df['y_data']

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins = [800,600])

extent = [0, xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
heatmap = normalize(heatmap)
heatmap = gaussian_filter(heatmap, 16)   

colors = [(1,1-c,0,c) for c in np.linspace(0,1,100)]
cmapred = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', colors, N=5)

map_img = mpimg.imread('dir/to/background/image.png')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16.1, 9.1))

plt.imshow(map_img, extent=[0, 800, 0, 600], cmap = 'Greys_r')
plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent = extent, origin = 'lower', cmap = cmapred, alpha = 0.7)

plt.ylim([0,600])
plt.xlim([0,800])
plt.show()
```

[Image of heatmap + background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcsXT.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcsXT.jpg

[Image of only heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRv5c.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRv5c.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add rows to your heat map manually.  Maybe easier is to try setting the histogram bins explicitly?

```
bins=[np.arange(0, 800, 1), np.arange(0, 600, 1)]
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)
```